# ¿Cómo obtener el último valor insertado en la BD Oracle XE?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, oracle-11g, jdbc

Estoy trabajando en JEE, con WebLogic y OracleXE como motor de base de datos, estoy utilizando un DataSource (NO JPA), en esta base de datos se deben de crear secuencias para generar valores autoincrementales, eso ya lo hice y me funciona bien cuando lo ejecuto ya que tambien me cree un triger para generar el valor automticamente aunque eso es otro tema.

Desde mi aplicacion puedo insertar datos a la base de datos, pero necesito obtener el valor de ese ID que menciono en el parrafo anterior.

ya este ejemplo que tome de internet lo ejecute y no me funciona, ni siquiera inserta los valores:

> INSERT INTO Orders (CustomerID, EmployeeID, OrderDate....)
>   VALUES (1, 1...)
>   RETURNING OrderID INTO :last_insert_id

¿Alguna otra sugerencia?

Aquí un poco de código

```
  > PreparedStatement sttmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO fabricantes (NOMBRE, PAIS) VALUES (?,?)", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

    String nombre = "Colo Colo";
    String pais = "Chile";

    sttmt.setString(1, nombre);
    sttmt.setString(2, pais);


    int resultado = sttmt.executeUpdate();

    // ResultSet rs = sttmt.getGeneratedKeys();
    Long id = null;
    ResultSet rs = sttmt.getGeneratedKeys();

        if (rs.next()) {
            id = rs.getLong(1);
            // Long id = generatedKeys.getLong(1);
        }

    return id;
```

La tabla tambien tiene un dato `COD_FABRICANTE` que no se ve en el codigo de insercion porque se genera automaticamente, es la clave primaria que quiero obtener precisamente. El valor de `COD_FABRICANTE` se genera autoincrementalmente a traves de una secuencia que yo cree, en la base de datos Oracle 11g no existe un valor `IDENTITY` o valor `SERIAL` como en otras Bases de Datos. Por restriccion del Servidor WebLogic, estoy utilizando el JDK 6, la plataforma no soporta JDK superiores.

Comment: Incluye un [mcve] por favor.

Comment: No se como podras verificarlo pero aca te dejo un poco de codigo -> INSERT INTO fabricantes (NOMBRE, PAIS) VALUES (?,?) RETURNING COD_FABRICANTE INTO :last_insert_id      ..... Eso lo coloco dentro de un PreparedStatement, por eso los signos de interrogacion. COD_FABRICANTE es el ID autoincremental de la tabla (su PrimaryKey), justo el que menciono que se genera a traves de una secuencia, si quito la parte de RETURNIN y todo lo que esta a la derecha entonces el valor se inserta bien.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una manera que debería funcionar correctamente es rodeando tu sentencia `INSERT` con `BEGIN ... END;` para que se convierta en bloque PL/SQL. Esto debería permitir el uso de la cláusula `RETURNING`.

Luego usas un `CallableStatement` para poder registrar un parámetro de salida.

Ejemplo de código:

```
CallableStatement st = conn.prepareCall("BEGIN INSERT INTO fabricantes (NOMBRE, PAIS) VALUES (:nombre,:pais) RETURNING cod_fabricante INTO :cod_fabricante; END;");
st.setString("nombre", nombre);
st.setString("pais", pais);
st.registerOutParameter("cod_fabricante", java.sql.Types.BIGINT);
st.execute();
long id = st.getLong("cod_fabricante");
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias, me sirvio ese codigo.

Answer (score 0):

Por `jdbc` y con una `insert` sin el `returning`:

```
try(PreparedStatement st= connection.prepareStatement(miInsert, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)){
    st.setInt(1,XXX);
    ...
    st.executeUpdate();

    try (ResultSet rs = st.getGeneratedKeys()) {
        if (rs.next()) {
            Long id = rs.getLong(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Estoy teniendo problemas con esa linea Long id = generatedKeys.getLong(1);  No me reconoce la sentencia generatedKeys. Como informacion, estoy utilizando el JDK 6 por obligacion, el WebLogic 11g (el servidor) solo soporta esa version de JDK, no superiores.

Comment: Describe el problema, y la query que lanzas

Comment: Creo que la unica duda es mia, ese miInsert supongo es la sentencia SQL, si es asi entonces nos estaos entendiendo. El problema ya esta descrito, y lo entendiste porque lo que intentaste hacer es lo que quiero hacer.

Comment: Con la sentencia que me dices si se insertan los valores pero no obtengo el valor autogenerado, tomaste en cuenta que se esta generando por una secuencia sql?

Comment: ¿Has quitado el returning?

Comment: Si ya quite el RETURNING

Comment: Copia el código completo actualizado

Comment: Acabo de colocar codigo y un poco mas de descripcion.